# Why did Women's Day never really catch on in the US, even though it started there?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, soviet-union, social-history, cold-war

The roots of [International Women's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Women%27s_Day) (March 8th) go all the way back to New York City in 1909 and the Socialist Party of America. However, from what I have learned the International Women's Day is today little known or celebrated in the US (correct me if I'm wrong).

The same goes to [International Worker's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Workers%27_Day#Origin), or May Day (May 1), which goes back to 1885 and the American Federation of Labor (AFL) fighting for the 8-hour work day.

I've heard this may have something with their socialist roots because Russia (USSR) is the country championed these two holidays.

I am sure International Children's Day (June 1) is the case because it is celebrated on June 1 in most Communist and post-Communist countries even though it seemed to first started in US too.

Is this the case for International Women's Day, and is the status of International Worker's Day (May Day) in the US related?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 I think they do need to be separate questions because in UK - the BBC and many paers had large stories for Womens day - May Day tends to be political and won't have that large media coverage and I have not heard of Childrens' Day - so I think the answers will be unconnected

Comment: @mmmmmm The reason I put them together is because I believe they are the same reason, ie the political reason, these 3 holidays all have their socialist roots.

Comment: @mmmmmm - I've edited to make the relatedness of May Day a secondary question, rather than inherently part of the question. Hopefully that's good enough.

Comment: In the UK, the May Day holiday was introduced (by a Labour government) in the 1970s, but, like most of our public holidays, it is held on the nearest Monday to May 1. For centuries, celebrations marking the start of summer had been held on May Day, and I don't think the holiday is particularly associated with workers by the general public.

Comment: @T.E.D. I seem to remember that the question with downvote but no answer will be auto-deleted by bot. I hate to see the effort we spent in it is wasted (that is why I always hate downvote without any explanation). I did some research, which seems to confirm my suspect that it was because of political reason. But I never live in the US so I don't want to provide the answer I don't experience, so maybe you can provide an answer ?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 - I think that only happens if its closed.

Comment: @T.E.D. It happened to me at physics SE, https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions  but I don't know about history SE.

Comment: Well, for now I've forestalled the issue by upvoting it.